# How can I send a signal to a specific child to let it end

Tags: c, linux

Here's the code, I ran it but all three children ended themselves, but I specified in the code the the SIGTERM is only sent to the 3rd one.

The signal handler is really simple:

```
====================================================
void stop_handler(int signal_num)
{
         printf("Signal %d is received \n", signal_num);
}
====================================================
```

In main() I created 3 processes:

```
====================================================
       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                if( (pids[i] = fork()) < 0 ) {
                        printf("Fork failed!\n");
                        exit(2);
                } else if (pids[i] == 0) {
                        exit(do_childwork(i + 1));
                } else {
                        active_children++;
               }
        }
====================================================
```

The body of do_childwork is like this:

```
====================================================
int do_childwork(int i)
{
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if(signal(SIGTERM, stop_handler) == SIG_ERR) {
                        printf("signal install error\n");
                } else {
                        printf("Killed by parent\n");
                        return i * 5;
                }

                printf("sleeping %d for not getting signal\n", j);
                sleep(2);
        }
        return i * 3;

}
====================================================
```

And in main() sent to the 3rd process only:

```
====================================================
               printf("Sending signal to: %d\n", pids[2]);
               kill(pids[2], SIGTERM);
====================================================
```

But the 3 process got killed immediately once I ran it.

From the output I can tell I sent the signal to the right child process. I wrote the signal handler and the way to signal a process from google searches. So what did I do wrong and how to correct them?

Comment: Does the parent do anything to stay alive after sending the `kill` command?  Are you sure all the processes are dying due to a SIGTERM?

Comment: You should use `strace -f` to trace all of the processes, and in the log (`-o file`) you'll see what signal/event causes the death of each process.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how the [`signal(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) function works -- it simply installs a signal handler and returns immediately.  Your child processes aren't getting killed, they're just exiting normally because `signal()` succeeds, so `do_childwork()` prints out a message and returns immediately.

Comment: Read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html); you can't call `printf` from inside a signal handler (since `printf` is not *async-signal-safe*); read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to install the signal handler more than once. Just use a flag in your signal handler, and exit the loop when the flag is set, i.e.

```
static int flag = 0;

void stop_handler(int signal_num)
{
         printf("Signal %d is received \n", signal_num);
         flag = 1;
}

...

int do_childwork(int i)
{
        if(signal(SIGTERM, stop_handler) == SIG_ERR) {
                printf("signal install error\n");
                exit(1);
        }

        while (!flag) {
                printf("sleeping %d for not getting signal\n", j);
                sleep(2);
        }

        return i * 3;

}
```

Comment: That's a convenient way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: I saw lots of checking/blocking in signal code examples, do I need to use any of them here?

Comment: @user3166982 - If I understood your comment here, you don't need to handle all kinds of signal. There are reasons why some code will need a signal that other codes may not. As an example, if you are writing to or reading from a socket connection, you will receive SIGPIPE if the other end closes the connection. In this situation you will need to handle the signal appropriately.